# Nested FormGroupDirective in child components

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, dependency-injection

There is a problem with `FormGroupDirective` dependency injection. I have an example of relation component to each other:

```
<app-component-group>
  <child-group>
    <child-control></child-control>
  </child-group>
</app-component-group>
```

There I have `FormGroup` in the parent component,
in the first child component -  nested `FormGroup`, and in the last child control component - nested `FormControl`.

Code is simple:

`child-group.ts`

```
...

constructor(private parentForm: FormGroupDirective) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.parentForm.form.addControl('group', new FormGroup({}));
}

...
```

`child-control.ts`

```
...

constructor(private parentForm: FormGroupDirective) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.parentForm.form.addControl('testControl', new FormControl());
}

...
```

But here I got the problem!

Injector for `FormGroupDirective` is relative to the root element (app-component-group). And I got wrong result: `formGroup: { group: {}, control }` instead of what I need: `formGroup: { group: { control } }`.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eeuoca)

Comment: Did you resolve this?  I'm facing the same question right now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You have to add this in `child.component.ts`

```js
viewProviders: [
    { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective },
]
```

example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qpaihe?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.ts

Comment: What you've shown is different. You're only doing a single child. The problem is when it's a child of a child.